# Why can't the compiler see this `From` impl?

Tags: rust, serde

I recently attempted to use [format_serde_error](https://crates.io/crates/format_serde_error), a crate that formats serde error messages. I've found that the example does not appear to compile. The following snippet:

```rust
use format_serde_error::SerdeError;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    x: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let content = "x: 3";
    let foo = serde_yaml::from_str(content)
        .map_err(|err| SerdeError::new(content.to_string(), err))
        .unwrap();
    println!("Read in {:?}", foo);
}
```

with the accompanying `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "ser-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
format_serde_error = { version = "0.3.0", features = ["serde_yaml"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.183", features = ["derive"] }
serde_yaml = "0.9.25"
```

Produces the inscrutable:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ErrorTypes: From<serde_yaml::Error>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:12:61
    |
12  |         .map_err(|err| SerdeError::new(content.to_string(), err))
    |                        ---------------                      ^^^ the trait `From<serde_yaml::Error>` is not implemented for `ErrorTypes`
    |                        |
    |                        required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <ErrorTypes as From<serde_json::error::Error>>
              <ErrorTypes as From<serde_yaml::error::Error>>
              <ErrorTypes as From<(Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)>, std::option::Option<usize>, std::option::Option<usize>)>>
    = note: required for `serde_yaml::Error` to implement `Into<ErrorTypes>`
note: required by a bound in `SerdeError::new`
   --> /home/c/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/format_serde_error-0.3.0/src/lib.rs:278:41
    |
278 |     pub fn new(input: String, err: impl Into<ErrorTypes>) -> SerdeError {
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SerdeError::new`
```

The reason I deem this *inscrutable* is that, in both the [code on github](https://github.com/AlexanderThaller/format_serde_error/blob/b114501c468bfe4f0a8c3f48f84530414bdeeaa1/src/lib.rs#L262-L267), and the lib.rs file mentioned in the compiler output, this 'missing' From impl is defined as so:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "serde_yaml")]
impl From<serde_yaml::Error> for ErrorTypes {
    fn from(err: serde_yaml::Error) -> Self {
        Self::Yaml(err)
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the compiler does not see this `From` impl. I have updated rust (running `1.73.0-nightly (f3623871c 2023-08-06)`) and `cargo clean`'ed, nothing changes. This behavior does not change if I use default feature flags, or specify `serde_yaml`.

Even more confusingly, my code is a total (accidental) plagiarism of [an example](https://github.com/AlexanderThaller/format_serde_error/blob/main/examples/serde_yaml.rs) provided by `format_serde_error`.

For those who want to reproduce it exactly, here is a series of shell commands that reproduces the issue on my machine:

```
cargo new ser-test
cd ser-test
cargo add serde --features derive
cargo add serde_yaml
cargo add format_serde_error
echo Copy the snippet into main.rs here
cargo run
```

Comment: format_serde_error depends on serde_yaml 0.8, you depend on 0.9, those are incompatible.

Comment: cargo pulls in both, but types from each are distinct, and the one you are using does not have a From impl.

Comment: It's a shame that Rust error reporting doesn't include the crate version in the error itself. It leaves it to you to wonder what went wrong.

Comment: @IvanC I see. Thank you for the answer! If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct, otherwise I'll post your answer as the official one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@ivan-c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12015230/ivan-c) correctly identified the issue: `format_serde_error` used a different version of `serde_yaml` then the one I had pulled in. This caused the issue. Solutions are either:

1.) Explicitly specify `serde_yaml` version `0.8`

2.) Update `format_serde_error` to use the newer version, [like this](https://github.com/AlexanderThaller/format_serde_error/pull/23)